# Calculate $\lim_{k\to\infty} \int_0^1 \frac{x^k+1}{x^k+3}$.

Tags: integration

My sketch is as follows.

---

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \int_0^1 \frac{x^k+1}{x^k+3}dx = \lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^11-\frac{2}{x^k+3}dx$$
$$= 1 - \int_0^1\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{2}{x^k+3}dx = 1-\int_0^1\frac23dx = \frac13 $$

Is it right? I don't know whether to change integrate and limit.

Comment: the dominated convergence theorem says you can change integration and limiting

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's right and you can interchange limit and integral by the monotone convergence theorem.

**Remark** You can also from the beginning interchange limit and integral using the dominated convergence theorem.